# How do I get NFC tag id

Tags: android, tags, nfc

This is a question already asked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815718/getting-the-nfc-hardware-id-in-android), but no answer was given. Since then, however, we have Android 4.4 and new nfc APIs but, as far as I can tell, there is still no way to get my own nfc tag ID (i.e. the one that readers would eventually discover when scanning the device).

Can anybody confirm this or provide sample code for such a task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check my NFC TAG ID (UID)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195762/how-to-check-my-nfc-tag-id-uid)

Comment: If that's the case i think there should be a way to program the controller with a specific UID since the application logic may rely on it