# How to get the unique nfc id of a phone, without reading nfc on android?

Tags: android, nfc

I know How to get Nfc Unique ID, When NFC Reader,

```
private Tag tag;

//Read success.
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   super.onNewIntent(intent);

   tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

   byte[] id = tag.getId();
```

}

but I want Even if I do not read the NFC card.

How to get NFC id, without reading nfc on android?

thanks.

Comment: What ID do you expect to get? The UID of the phone when it acts as a contactless card?

Comment: If yes, then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25195762/2425802

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27239473/2425802 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19764476/2425802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile phones acting as a tag (card emulation) do have a random UID (4 byte). It is not supported to adjust a specific UID.

As result every time the external field is turned off and on again the mobile phone as a different UID.

Best regards,